# javascript check if regex apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

First of all, here is my code snippet:

```
var str = '<!--:de-->some german text<!--:--><!--:en-->some english text<!--:-->';
var match =  str.match(/de-->([^<]+).+?en[^>]+>([^<]+)/i);
var textInDe = match[1]; 
var textInEn = match[2];
```

I've got this regex validation (thanks to The Mask) which works great.

Now, I want to check with an if-statement if this regex applies to some string or not. 
I'm using Javascript jquery.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use [RegExp.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp/test)

```
if(/de-->([^<]+).+?en[^>]+>([^<]+)/i.test(str)) {
   // something
}
```

Comment: hm i dont really know how it should work?!
how it would looks like in an if statement? if(…== true) or what?

Comment: @YeppThat'sMe You don't need to have `== true` in an if statement, literally ever. Maybe `=== true`, but definitely not the other

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = '<!--:de-->some german text<!--:--><!--:en-->some english text<!--:-->';
var match =  str.match(/de-->([^<]+).+?en[^>]+>([^<]+)/i);
if(match.length > 0){
//successful match
}
```

OR

```
var re = new RegExp('regex string');
  if (somestring.match(re)) {
//successful match
}
```

Comment: If there are no matches then `match` is `null` meaning you can't do `match.length`. If you change the if statement `if (match){...` then it will work.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
function IsMatch(v) {
   //basically build your regex here
   var exp = new RegExp("^de-->([^<]+).+?en[^>]+>([^<]+)$"); return exp.test(v);
}

To call it:
if(IsMatch('Your string')) alert('Found'); else alert('Not Found');
```