# changing text box border color if validation is failed

Tags: javascript, css, validation

I have a text box with the id : txtFirstName, and a RequiredFieldValidator to it.
How can i change the textbox border color if the validator is not valid?
Here is my code:

```
<label class="lblForm">FirstName</label><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" placeholder="Enter First Name"></asp:TextBox><br />
<label class="lblForm valMes">
<!-- First Name Validate -->
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ErrorMessage="EnterFirstName" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="First name not Valis" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ValidationExpression="[a-z]{2,10}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</label>
```

I tries many javascript functions that didn't work.. can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

> you can use `:invalid` and `:valid` Selectors Like This :

```css
#txtFirstName:invalid {
   border: 2px solid red;
}

#txtFirstName:valid {
   border: 2px solid green;
}
#txtFirstName {
   outline: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="lblForm">FirstName</label><br />
<input type="text" required="required" id="txtFirstName" pattern="[a-z]{2,10}">
```

Comment: How can i make it work after the user press the Send button? i dont wnt it to be red from the beggining

Comment: and also, is there a way to change the label color too?

Comment: almost, i just need it to become red after the first click on the SEND button, and not from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code :-

```
 var sportsDescription=  $('#sportsDescription').val();
 if(sportsDescription == ''){
      $('#sportsDescription').css({ "border":"2px solid red"  });
      mandatoryFlag = true;
 }else{
      $('#sportsDescription').css({ "border": "3px solid #D2D2D2" });
 }
```

Comment: it works only for Required validation, what about the Regular Exprassion?

Comment: I guess you have to give the valid regex expression inside the if block and swipe the contents of both if and else blocks **eg:-** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390695/javascript-check-if-regex-apply

Comment: so basicly i need to do the validation in javasccript, but im trying to check if the text box is valid using the validators

Comment: Its up to you, if you feel comfortable with client side validation you can do that, otherwise you can do server side validation and I'm not well versed in ASP.